# Flask - Method not allowed

Tags: python, flask

I'm running through an intro Flask tutorial and hitting an error. ' The fuller error message in the command line is: "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 405".  From these two files any idea where I am going wrong?
http://opentechschool.github.io/python-flask/core/form-submission.html

```html
<!-- index.html in the templates folder -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cats Everywhere!</title> 

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sintony:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">    
  body
  {
    background-color:#000;
  }

  h1
  {
    font-size:48px;
    margin-top:0;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow:2px 0 15px #292929;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#DDD;
  }

  #banner
  {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/MQHYB.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:90px auto auto;
    padding:80px 0;
  }

  .lead
  {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 3px;
    font-family:Sintony, sans-serif;
  }
    </style>

</head>  

<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1>cats everywhere</h1>
        <p class="lead">We're bringing cats to the internet. Free. Cute. Awesome.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="emailform">
        <form action="/signup" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Signup"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
#catseverywhere.py file:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    author = "Me"
    name = "RandomName"
    return render_template('index.html', author=author, name=name)

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():    
    email = request.form['email']
    print("The email address is '" + email + "'")
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is the exact URL that returns a 405? Flask tells you in the console what URLs are accessed.

Comment: The fuller error message in the command line is: "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 405

Comment: You may want to add that to your post, though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the code you posted; the form works as designed. The console prints `The email address is 'abcd'` and `127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 15:00:57] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 302 -` (302 is the redirect).

Comment: Why are you trying to GET the /signup route? You go to the homepage, and use the form there. `GET /signup` means you tried to go to `http://localhost:5000/signup` in your browser, *or* misconfigured the `<form>` tag to not have a (correct) `method` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you misunderstood how the `/signup` route *works*.

The homepage holds the form; visit `http://localhost:5000/` in your browser and you'll see a white textbox and `signup` button there. Text you fill into that box will be posted to the server

The console would look like:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 15:00:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 15:00:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
The email address is 'abcd'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 15:00:57] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 15:00:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

where `GET /` is the browser fetching the homepage with form, the `POST /signup` is the form being posted, which then issues a 302 redirect back to the homepage, which is fetched by the browser next.

The `/signup` route, as configured, can only handle a `POST` request, like what the browser produces for the form result. You don't normally visit it in the browser; entering `http://localhost:5000/signup` produces a `GET` request instead.

In other words, the error you see is *by design*; the route only supports POST requests.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's it.  I fundamentally misunderstood how things work.